# For DataContract serializing getting error: xmlns=''> was not expected

Tags: c#, serialization

I have the following class defined:

```
[DataContract(Name = "DataContractTest", Namespace = "")]
public class DataContractTestClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public string TheString { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public Guid TheGuid { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "TheNumber")]
    public int TheInteger { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public DateTime TheDateTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public decimal? TheDecimal { get; set; }
}
```

And the following two methods:

```
        private static byte[] SerializeContent<T>(T content)
    {
        var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            formatter.Serialize(memoryStream, content);
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }

        private static T DeserializeObject<T>(byte[] contentBytes)
    {
        var xml = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(contentBytes);
        using (var memoryStream = new StringReader(xml))
        {
            var formatter = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            return (T) formatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
        }
    }
```

I can call SerializeContent() then call DeserializeContent() with the result of the serialize but get an error trying to deserialize.

> System.InvalidOperationException: DataContractTestClass xmlns='' was not expected.

Why am I getting this error when I try to deserialize and object just serialized by C#?

Comment: And when you omit `Namespace = ""` ?

Comment: But do post the actual roundtrip code, this often comes down to not resetting a MemoryStream or something similar.

Comment: Just copy/pasted and ran this but no repro.

Comment: Symmetry is golden in this kind of op. Why bother with `Encoding.UTF8` in one leg but not in the other? (Deserialize() will accept a stream).

Comment: I was doing the GetString so that I could easily inspect the XML in the debugger.  When I just work off the byte[] contentBytes I get the same result.

Comment: That I can't reproduce.